# Excel Filter - Show Button on top of cell

Tags: vba, excel, filter

If you create a Table in Excel all columns get an autofilter.The Button is always shown on the right of the columnheader:

[image: Picture of Button position]

My Table has ~60 Columns. To safe horizontal space i would like to move the Button on top/below the cell:

[image]

Does anybody know how to move a autofilterbutton on top of a cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a space on the cell above.

Comment: That's a great workaround! I can use the numbers in the first row, then a empty row with the buttons and then content. Can't believe i hadn't thoought of that.

Comment: I know how you feel. I also sometimes overthink things. :)